# Why isn't the ODR violated by taking the address of an inline-defined static const integral member variable?

Tags: c++, static-members, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Something like this would be an obvious violation of the C++ one definition rule if it compiled:

```
// Case 1
// something.h

struct S {};

struct A
{
   static const S val = S();
};
```

because if something.h were include in more than one module, the definition of `A::val` would be repeated. However, this is allowed:

```
// Case 2    
// someOtherThing.h

struct B
{
   static const int val = 3;
};
```

As I understand it, the reason this case is ok is because `B::val` is a compile-time constant of integral type, so the compiler can essentially do a search-and-replace of all references to `B::val` with a literal `3` (and examination of the disassembly shows this is exactly what it does). Therefore, there are in a sense *zero* definitions of `B::val` in the final product, so the ODR does not apply. However, consider this:

```
// Case 3
// yetAnotherThing.h

struct C
{
   static const int val = 3;

   const int* F()
   {
      return &val;
   }
};
```

This is permitted, and the disassembly shows that in this case, some memory location has actually been set aside to store the value of `C::val`. On the surface, this means we now violate the ODR if yetAnotherThing.h is included in multiple modules since `static const int val = 3` now causes storage to be "emitted". Yet neither the compiler nor the linker (VC++2012) complains.

Why? Is this just an obnoxious special case that authors of compilers/linkers have to deal with? And if so, why can't the same system be used to make case #1 work too?

(Relevant quotes from the standard are welcome, but they won't necessarily answer the question. If the standard said that any usage of the `pink_elephants` keyword should cause every instance of the number 42 to be replaced with 666 then that would be that, but we'd still be left wondering why such a weird rule exists.)

Comment: What is your question? Why reasonable and convenient things are allowed by the standard? Because they are reasonable and convenient.

Comment: @n.m. I would question whether #3 is reasonable given that is presumably requires the compiler to jump through a bunch of hoops to make it work in exchange for a (IMO) very small convenience. But if it is, then #1 would certainly be reasonable and convenient as well, yet it is forbidden.

Comment: It doesn't work. If you use a non-inline function F (so the whole thing isn't removed), you will notice (with gcc) that the symbol _ZN1C3valE is undefined.

Comment: The compiler already has to do this work for static members of templates classes, so removing this feature doesn't really save any work for the compiler writer. The difference between this and case #1 is that in case #1, the compiler cannot prove that the multiple definitions of `val` are identical.

Comment: @MarcGlisse The above is just example code. I have a real project that does something like #3 and that has multiple calls to "F" in multiple files, and everything builds and runs fine with VS2012. Maybe this is another Microsoft-specific extension?

Comment: @RaymondChen I buy that, but what about (for example) `static const double val = 3.0`? This is also forbidden since `double` is not integral, but in this case the compiler could deduce that all definitions are identical, right?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Nothing here is forbidden, however, "The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used" (9.4.2/3). So if you have not done this, then the Microsoft compiler is letting you get away with it.

Comment: @n.m. If it isn't defined, it is undefined behavior.  So there's nothing wrong with the compiler letting him get away with it.

Comment: How does the compiler know that some other file wasn't compiled with a different header file that says `static const double val = 3.14;`? That isn't known until link time, at which point the compiler's decision as to whether to emit a COMDAT is long gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is *not* a violation of the ODR, because the
declaration of a static member inside a class is not
a definition, only a declaratin.  The static member must be
defined in a single translation unit, e.g.:

```
S const A::val;
```

in a source file (not a header).

In pre-C++11, when the declaration was static, had integral type
and was const, it was permitted (as a special exception) to
specify an initializer, provided the initializer was a constant
integral expression.  Even in this case, however, you formally
needed the definition (without an initializer) in one, and only
one source file.  If it was missing, the results were undefined
behavior.  (IIFC, with one exception: if the variable was only
used in contexts which required an integral constant expression,
no definition was required.)

I think C++11 has extended this some, and allows some
non-integral types as well to have an initializer in the class
definition.  But it still requires the definition outside of the
class.

Concerning your final example, which you claim works: it is
*not* legal in pre-C++11, and it causes errors in many
compilers.  (I was under the impression that C++11 made it
legal, and left it up to the compiler to generate the instance,
but I can't find the appropriate words off-hand.  If it was made
legal in C++11, then this is just a C++11 feature which VC++2012
implements.)

Comment: Oops; you're right about case #1; I edited it to contain an assignment since that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @dlf c++11 allows case 1 if you replace const with constexpr. Legal or not this is not an ODR violation since there is no definition here, just a declaration, even with an initialiser in place.

Comment: @n.m. I was under the (mis)apprehension that cases two and three involved locating the member's *definition* inside the class definition. In fact, as you and James Kanze have made clear, all that's happening is that the *initialization* is being located with what is still just a declaration. That realization and the standard section you quoted below the question clear things up for me.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The parenthetical comment in your last paragraph seems to be incorrect based on 9.4.2/3 of the C++11 draft, as quoted by n.m. below the question. Unless this was changed after the draft?

Comment: @dlf There's no assignment in any of your examples; there's no context where an assignment operator would be legal.  All are simply specifying the initialization of a static data member.

Comment: @dlf That's where I looked, too.  I just remember some discussion in the standards committee about allowing the definition to be absent.  Apparently, it didn't make it into the final cut (unless someone can point out somewhere else in the standard which says it did).  So omitting the definition remains undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze "Even in this case, however, you formally needed the definition (without an initializer) in one, and only one source file." If I put `static const int val = 3;` inside the definition of `MyClass` in a header and also put `const int MyClass::val;` in the cpp, I get a linker error ("MyClass::val already defined in [some other cpp that included the header]"). What's going on here? Is Microsoft blatantly violating the standard?

Comment: Evidently, omitting the out-of-class definition is a Microsoft-specific extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx. What they don't tell you is that if you enable this "feature", you MUST NOT include an out-of-class definition, or you'll get a linker error.

Comment: @dlf Interesting.  We've a number of statics in this case; I just checked, and we don't define any of them, so we've had no problems with Microsoft.  Nor with g++, because as it happens, all of the uses of them are in contexts where the compiler can just substitute the actual value, and doesn't need an object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54665/discussion-between-dlf-and-james-kanze).